# gpg: xxxx: skipped: public key not found

Tags: encryption, gnupg, .net-framework, c#

I'm getting this error:

> gpg: xxxx: skipped: public key not found  gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: public key not found

I'm using this code:

```
IEncryptionService encryptionService = new EncryptionService(@"C:\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe"); 
var encryptedFile = encryptionService.EncryptFile("xxxx", @"D:\application\" + NewFileName + ".GFM", @"D:\GPGFILE\" + NewFileName + ".GPG");
```

I would appreciate any guidance, advice, or assistance in helping me get this resolved.

Comment: put all keys like pubring, secring and pub.id in the C:\GNU\GnuPG\ ..it's really work